# How to send request to Ooyala Player API using player id and namespace in V4 version

Tags: aem, ooyala

We are migrating from OOyala V3 player to V4 player. In V3 player while implementing model and in play functionality we are making call like below url.

```
//player.ooyala.com/v3/7d6bf067c5f4e73a8a70d068aca2ef7?namespace=tmOOsports
```

now can anyone help us is there any url available for the v4 player to make a call in the same manner of v3 so that it will be helpful.